# compiling a small C++ program with Visual C++ Express

Tags: visual-c++

I opened hello.cpp. Why isn't there File -> Compile -> hello.cpp? What is an other easy way, if any?

Comment: Delirium Tremems, I usually have one of those after an "Arrogant Bastard Ale" and wind up with a "Blithering Idiot."  It just seems like a natural progression.

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880803/running-small-c-programs-in-visual-studio-without-creating-projects/880861#880861

Comment: Is there a way to Merge duplicate questions rather than just closing them?  I mean it would make sense to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file must be part of a project before you can compile/build it.  Starting with VS 2005 (or maybe 2008), you can use *File -> New -> Project From Existing Code* to wrap a project around source files.

Comment: It's kinda a pain in the ass if you're used to being able to just type gcc Hello.cpp.  But overall it gives you a nice view graph of your application files, and classes.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use something like notepad++ and write a script that compiles with the windows 7/Visual studio C++ compile (CL.exe). That could work as well and do what you describe. C++ was meant for medium and large size projects that require performance and space efficiency. If you want to practice you could use the method I described but otherwise I'd recommend using something like Python/Java/PHP/etc to crank out applications that can take the performance hit of an interpreted/JIT compiled language. This will allow you to develop at a rapid pace. I prefer C++ myself but I use the approach very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

The best way its to create an empty project add your `hello.cpp` then Visual Studio will build your program.