# How to compile source C++ code that doesn't have a project file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation

I have just started learning more about C/C++ and I am using Visual Studio 2013 to manage the code.

A project I am working on to use the Tobii EyeX eye gaze system requires me to be able to tweak this code slightly, however I do not understand how I can compile this code to an exe file without a Microsoft Visual Studio project file. This is that code:

https://github.com/MastaLomaster/bkb

In the source folder you see all the project's files but not an actual project file. How would I go about compiling this code? Where do I start? I can not seem to be able to load this is Visual Studio at all - the programmer of the code says (at the bottom of the Github page):

> Compiling the source codes As for now, you have to use Microsoft
> Visual Studio 2012 (latest update preferred)...

Comment: You import the source into a new project file as existing items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Visual C++, compiling small source codes without project file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393740/microsoft-visual-c-compiling-small-source-codes-without-project-file)

Comment: Figure out if a makefile exists in source code. Visual Studio supports makefiles.

Comment: Remember I am a absolute beginner. I am coming from a world of run time program languages and that perspective. When I am looking at this src folder https://github.com/MastaLomaster/bkb/tree/master/source is there a Index file that everything starts with?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you I will try that.

Comment: @Poldie Thank you. I've seen and read that question. If there are some answers that answer my questions there, they are far too complex for a beginner to understand. For example in my case, which file is the file that I ask the command prompt to compile? In the languages I am familiar with there is always an Index or go to file that initiates everything, how does one know which file that is this folder? https://github.com/MastaLomaster/bkb/tree/master/source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a makefile(if no makefile is exist) for visual studio using nmake or you can use the suggestion provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393740/microsoft-visual-c-compiling-small-source-codes-without-project-file) link.

Additionally you can create a project by adding these codes as source. follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx) link.