# How to compile a C++ File without making a project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, projects

I want to compile a C++ source file without making a project in visual studio 2017 without making a project like we do in some code editors, how can I do that. Can anyone please tell?

Here is an example, in sublime text, I create a code and then compile it by ctrl + b.In a similar manner, I want to do that in visual studio 2017.

Comment: [Invoke the `cl.exe` compiler frontend program directly from the command line?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx)

Comment: Not possible with the IDE (can be done from the command line).  My workaround is to have a permanent "playpen" project into which I can drop test files or copy-paste code.

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880803/running-small-c-programs-in-visual-studio-without-creating-projects/52800795#52800795?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run cl.exe from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84404/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open a folder and start coding in visual studio without creating a project or solution file.

They call it the [*Open Folder*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/non-msbuild-projects) feature.

> Visual Studio 2017 introduces the "Open Folder" feature, which enables you to open a folder of source files and immediately start coding with support for IntelliSense, browsing, refactoring, debugging, and so on. No .sln or .vcxproj files are loaded...
>
> from the main menu select File | Open | Folder or press Ctrl + Shift + Alt + O.

The easiest way I found from there is to right click in the "Solution Explorer" area and select "Open Developer Command Prompt". From there you can use [cl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiling-a-c-cpp-program) to compile your program however you see fit.

Comment: I think that Developer Command Prompt method was easier , i left VSCODE because of the '.json' configuration.Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can open "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" at the start menu and use cl.exe to compile your source code.

E.g. 
c++ source file name: test.cpp
type "cl test.cpp"
Then, it will generate "test.obj" and "test.exe" if no bugs found.

You can type "cl" for simple usage and "cl /?" for complete help.

Comment: well `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /Tc yourfile.c` (you can also create individual directories for `obj` and `exe` files to keep your source dir clean and add `/Foname1/` and `/Fename2/` to put `.obj` files in a directory called `name1` and your executables in `name2`) It works the same to C++, just use `/Tp` for the file type.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get away from the IDEs I would recommend looking up MinGW for compiling in the command prompt. If you are running Ubuntu or something similar I believe you can compile in bash without further extensions.

For MinGW http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto

I believe you compile in the same way in ubuntu if not I believe you can find some sources for that aswell.

Pros about compiling in the terminal is mostly that you do not have to setup a complete project but you can make your own personal little setup. Of course an IDE is a simple way to start but compiling in the terminal also helps you understand what is actually happening instead of just pressing "Debug".